# GIT - fatal: unable to read tree

Tags: git

```
Изначально все начиналось с пустого файла в git
```

Исправлял обычно я это по [этим рекомендациям](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty) 
Но в этот раз все закончилось хуже. Теперь если делаю

```
>git status
```

В ответ

```
fatal: unable to read tree d4244fdbb42c7d5151ae6f9b8b8a8fc3ac0a3358
```

На  `>git fsck --full`

В ответ

```
  error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
    error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/05/2fd5b6e04371bd92c15078e145cb25
    e4484fa9
    error: 052fd5b6e04371bd92c15078e145cb25e4484fa9: object corrupt or missing: .git
    /objects/05/2fd5b6e04371bd92c15078e145cb25e4484fa9
    error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
    error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/55/49f3791a325090bef0c03b79b9c5de
    490d5ff1
    error: 5549f3791a325090bef0c03b79b9c5de490d5ff1: object corrupt or missing: .git
    /objects/55/49f3791a325090bef0c03b79b9c5de490d5ff1
    error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
    error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/74/836986e36dbc95b9c0292c13834735
    29507c4b
    error: 74836986e36dbc95b9c0292c1383473529507c4b: object corrupt or missing: .git
    /objects/74/836986e36dbc95b9c0292c1383473529507c4b
    error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
    error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/a2/04da236a49016f18da3d4e5e46155a
    022dcbf4
    error: a204da236a49016f18da3d4e5e46155a022dcbf4: object corrupt or missing: .git
    /objects/a2/04da236a49016f18da3d4e5e46155a022dcbf4
    error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
    error: unable to unpack header of .git/objects/d4/e172dd721dcc19ca01e48756626664
    9534734a
    error: d4e172dd721dcc19ca01e487566266649534734a: object corrupt or missing: .git
    /objects/d4/e172dd721dcc19ca01e487566266649534734a
    Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 5261ec4ca4bab7aed7924f4eff00fd4f9ee5484e
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 5261ec4ca4bab7aed7924f4eff00fd4f9ee5484e
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry be53507d7d923669c00edc73a55378417b3f1ffd
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry be53507d7d923669c00edc73a55378417b3f1ffd
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 53a5a8fcfb5ed57552fd5f5660bc1a245e315091
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 53a5a8fcfb5ed57552fd5f5660bc1a245e315091
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 53a5a8fcfb5ed57552fd5f5660bc1a245e315091
    error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 53a5a8fcfb5ed57552fd5f5660bc1a245e315091
    error: refs/heads/Возврат: invalid reflog entry be53507d7d923669c00edc73a5537841
    7b3f1ffd
    error: refs/heads/Возврат: invalid reflog entry be53507d7d923669c00edc73a5537841
    7b3f1ffd
    broken link from    tree 8a0102a2ad19206a5613367555117e56a82157c1
                  to    tree d4244fdbb42c7d5151ae6f9b8b8a8fc3ac0a3358
    dangling blob 2800623130df134e1f544604dc53e8fafc78d219
    dangling blob 5080875d0197a3fc6ca10736a26b9e7b6674f6a7
    dangling blob fdf1d542b493bd42cf2c3ad3aa3d0d7dc4d39e83
    dangling blob a58a0a6e8e400aa34dc159c24116a837fe58eb76
    dangling tree b2f2c33fac48e87c0458260e913ae53ddcc8673d
    dangling blob f7e39ab9cb440476c0286ac098d893080057c1ee
    dangling blob 282451dec8dab7f1c542152c816f7da5cb603658
    missing tree d4244fdbb42c7d5151ae6f9b8b8a8fc3ac0a3358
    dangling tree a6bd2176532a272ca4cda9722eb7bbb4ea3d2fbe
    dangling tree 2e6ffd2da47b5a6e4ad08e0c4b023671c6a6230f
    dangling blob c96fc5ec6a120590c82af7abe2185ba8a8c77593
    dangling tree ef9f2c46eba658ebb7e3ae32dde651460679c343
    dangling blob f11f2c92367abb9b953ccb721c07102e60582dd5
```

файла d4244fdbb42c7d5151ae6f9b8b8a8fc3ac0a3358 такого нету

Уже столько способов перепробовал. но видимо я чего то не понимаю. Помогите плиз

Comment: А какой версией гит Вы пользуетесь? может быть в какой то момент переехали на более сильно древний гит? А может просто диск испортился...

Comment: Решил. повторно восстановив по данные на копии [по этой рекомендации](http://qaru.site/questions/11178/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty)

Comment: Ответ удалили из очереди проверок — восстановил его как комментарий.

Comment: Файла такого и не будет, первый байт уходит в название каталога.